# Paytm Integration in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework, payment-gateway

I am new to Ionic framework and would like to integrate `Paytm` in the Ionic application.I could not find any articles which help to start development to integrate `paytm` in Ionic.

The thing I did so far is, I have visited http://paywithpaytm.com/developer.html and provided the details in the form and waiting for their response for few hours.

Please anybody help me for finding the solution.

Comment: I dont think that you can do it without any backend. And paytm provides backend libraries for many frameworks. You can choose one of them based on your backend.

Comment: You can use the iOS sdk and write your own Cordova plugin and then write an angular wrapper for that -- that's what I had to do for Parse Push plugin stuff: but I don't know how Paytm works to say if that's what you have to do.

Answer (score -1):

I have found this plugin that wraps things, have not tried it but looks like this will work

https://github.com/samyam-a/PayTM-PhoneGap-Plugin